# Router crashes if connection is established to server behind NAT, when connection to server is established from device in same internal Network

Tags: networking

Router 1 crashes sometimes if I establish a connection from PC-->Server with the external Internet IP (example.net). Especially on heavy load actions like an upload. But low loads like just opening the website works well.

If I directly connect from PC-->Server with the internal IP it works.
Connections from outside to the Server are working without problems.

My questions is especially why it fails? And secondly how to fix it?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because Router 1 is not supporting [NAT Hairpinning](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPq82kq__oAhWCjqQKHfC8ArYQFjACegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHairpinning&usg=AOvVaw0YQLb4sQoT-5b6LWWc1lTm).

One solution would be to edit the `/etc/hosts` file in one of the devices (PC or Router 2) and map the domain accordingly to the local ip of the Server. But this solution is not very dynamic.

Other solutions are already better discussed [there](https://superuser.com/questions/1047745/access-external-ip-from-inside-the-network).